# Windows 7 Explorer keeps crashing

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I currently have an issue with Windows Explorer.
It keeps crashing when I browse through a network drive.

This is happening on several computers.

I have already obtained a crash dump file but it doesn't state much:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\LocalDumps\explorer.exe.3964.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Mon Oct 21 11:21:30.000 2013 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:06:20.449
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:05:54.000
................................................................
................................................................
....
Loading unloaded module list
.............
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(f7c.fe4): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=00000000 ebx=07a3f080 ecx=00000400 edx=00000000 esi=00000002 edi=00000000
eip=76e170f4 esp=07a3f030 ebp=07a3f0cc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
76e170f4 c3              ret
```

I've already tried removing certain context menu items. I disabled all unnecessary start-up items. Ran memtest86 and it looks fine on that end.

It also happens when I browse through my local disk.

Can anyone take a look into this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, so it happens with both the network drive and local files and on all of the systems? ಠ_ఠ

Comment: Yep it happens when browsing locally and through network mapped drive. I also noticed that it mostly happens after the network is populated in the navigation pane

Comment: That wouldn’t/shouldn’t have a (direct) effect on local files. I recall in XP, having a network-mapped drive that was offline would cause Explorer to hang for a minute or two, but I don’t think that is related to what you are experiencing (though it might share *some* kind of underlying cause). What do these specific systems have in common that is special/different from other systems? Are they all the same hardware? If not, then it is probably something about your network configuration; maybe a router or something that has an unusual string or something in its name…

Comment: run **!analyze -v** in windbg and post the output.

Comment: Actually I found a workaround fix. Since the problem is definitely related to "network" populating in the navigation pane, I simply disabled it by following this site: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/39699-network-add-remove-navigation-pane.html It seems to have stopped the crashing as the very least.